# Browser Rendered Page Appears Different When Scraped

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

opening this page https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/ESH20/options

in Nokogiri doesn't have the same elements as in the rendered page inside the browser.

How can I access the same source code as seen in the Browser DevTools from the scraper library?

this element in particular `<div class="bc-datatable"`...

is required an headless browser to get the right page code first?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the [TOS](https://www.barchart.com/terms#terms-of-use) which specifically deny what you're doing. I'd recommend visiting https://www.barchart.com/solutions/. Scraping a site is never as robust as taking advantage of a well-written API, especially one that's as dynamic as theirs. They have downloads available so use them.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages along with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially the "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!" section. SO is not a message list, it's more like an online reference book.

Comment: It is just for a bootcamo initial project

Answer (score 0):

That data is coming from a JSON endpoint:

[image]

So luckily no headless browser required this time.

Comment: Pity because I can't use for a scraper bootcamp project the. But cool because I can see how to find out those things now, DevTool + Network + Search